# pos or neg two-numbers in string match using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is it that this regex *almost* works to return an array of two strings that can be used as numbers, positive or negative, but the 2nd string has its negative sign dropped? I can think of workarounds for this using another line or two of code, but would really like to get the regex to do it right. Thanks in advance. (By the way, the idea here is that the string can be "123,321" or "12.3, 321" or "123 32.1" or any reasonable formatting of two reals or integers.)

```
s="-123.23, -456.0";
s.match(/^([+-]?\d*\.\d*)\W+([+-]?\d*.\d*)$/);
```

//-->["-123.23, -456.0", "-123.23", "456.0"]

Comment: The `-` is being consumed by `\W+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to match the entire line, you might consider just matching the numbers ...

```
var r = "-123.23, -456.0".match(/[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g);
console.log(r); //=> [ '-123.23', '-456.0' ]
```

Comment: This is better. And works to return more-dimensional arrays. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `[^\w-]+` instead `\W+`

```
s = "-123.23, -456.0";
s.match(/^([+-]?\d*\.\d*)[^\w-]+([+-]?\d*.\d*)$/)
```

Comment: Thank you. I won't bother you for an explanation, though I did ask for one. I'll look it up. If you have time to pop an explanation in there, go ahead. Or I might.